# semantic ui - remove sticky from an element after page load

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I have a project using Semantic UI that has a sticky header.  on certain events, content is loaded that requires the header to become non-sticky.

I attempted to use `$('header.ui.sticky').sticky('remove')`, based on a quick skimming of the source code, but it seems to be incorrect.

How do I remove sticky after instantiating?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `destroy` instead of `remove`.

```
$('.ui.sticky')
  .sticky('destroy')
;
```